# Data Visulization : Matplotlib and Numpy throwing value error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning. I was teaching myself data visualization with MATPLOTLIB. my code is pretty simple.

1. It takes a numpy array (**x = np.random.rand(1,100)) of shape=(1, 100)**).
2. It converts numpy array x into y(**y = np.sin(x)**).
3. Final task is to visualise this in a BAR(**plt.bar(x, y, label="BAR", color='r'**))

But it is throwing **VALUE ERROR**.Even though there are already answers to this question, but none seems to work so far for me.

In one answer for this question [By **unutbu**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

he explains that this error is raised "**whenever one tries to evaluate an array in boolean context**".
I am unable to understand how  I am using these arrays as boolean?

**MY CODE**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#arguments are shape: 1=row; 100=columns
x = np.random.rand(1, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

#bars
plt.bar(x, y, label='Bars1', color='pink')

#legends
plt.legend()

#show the figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 100)
```

with

```
x = np.random.rand(100)
```

The reason is that the former gives you an array of arrays (with one array inside, but it is still a 2D array overall with dimensions 1-by-100), while the latter gives you a 1D array (of length 100). In order to visualize it with `plt`, you need the latter.

Comment: But if x is 2d arrays of overall size 1-by-100 then it means y is also of the same dimension. Then why this error.?

Comment: If you want to use plt, x cannot be a 2D array, as you can see here: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html